# Express.js server strange calls

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express.js server running on a Windows server, in my tests to put it into production I received a strange call that I did not make, from what I understand it is an attempt to access my server, what I do not understand is if these calls are normal for all server / webpages online.

My server is running with Https with certificates created in Certbot, I have helmet enabled and x-power-by disabled. I have the server listening on port 443, but I plan to change this to another port.

Previously I received many calls like the following:

```
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:40 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 404 140 "-" "-"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:46 +0000] "GET /system_api.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:48 +0000] "GET /c/version.js HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:50 +0000] "GET /streaming/clients_live.php HTTP/1.1" 404 165 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:52 +0000] "GET /stalker_portal/c/version.js HTTP/1.1" 404 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:54 +0000] "GET /stream/live.php HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "-" "VLC/3.0.8 LibVLC/3.0.8"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:57 +0000] "GET /flu/403.html HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
138.197.190.182 - - [01/Jun/2022:21:00:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"

92.226.2.139 - - [11/May/2022:16:14:45 +0000] "GET /anaesthetist/goddaughters/betterment/Colombias.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 189 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)"
92.226.2.139 - - [11/May/2022:16:14:45 +0000] "GET /Yorkshires/TKO/chromes/limestone.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 175 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; BOIE8;ENUS)"
82.102.17.180 - - [11/May/2022:16:25:19 +0000] "GET http://dyn.epicgifs.net/test6956.php HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"

103.178.236.40 - - [22/Apr/2022:22:17:20 +0000] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "Go-http-client/1.`1"

92.118.160.1 - - [23/Apr/2022:14:23:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 139 "-" "NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com"
```

I understand that as long as I don't have anything in the addresses they are trying to access there is no problem, or am I wrong?

My concern is that I received several identical calls in a short period of time from the same IP, like this:

```
193.19.109.230 - - [26/Jul/2022:22:59:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
```

My question is,
With the security that I currently have, should I be very concerned about these calls?

Comment: This is a network admin/security question, not programming. Should you be "concerned"? Sure; security is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public Servers often get spammed with Requests like these. Attackers try to get Informations about your server by scanning for specific Sites. So they can find attack vectors (for example old PHP/Wordpress Versions with known issues).

Other Requests can come from Scanners searching indexing security leaks or sites in general.

This is completely normal for Servers exposed to the Internet.

Another Question like this can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/why-am-i-getting-strange-http-requests-for-non-existing-pages)